# Delayed variable expansion in bash

Tags: bash, sed, echo, expansion

I have a scenario where I `echo` multiple lines and `pipe` them to a translator, like this:

```
echo -n '
$error This is an error$defaults
$fatal THIS IS FATAL ERROR$defaults
 This is normal text
' | translate ansi

echo -n '
$error This is an error$defaults
$fatal THIS IS FATAL ERROR$defaults
 This is normal text
' | translate html
```

I first used `sed` to replace `ansi` with `html` codes, but due to the obvious speed issues, I would like to do something like this:

```
input="$(cat)"
if [ "$1" == ansi ]
then
    error="[1m[31m"
    fatal="[0m[30m[41m"
    defaults="[0m"
elif [ "$1" == html ]
then
    error='<span class="error">'
    fatal='<span class="fatal">'
    defaults='</span>'
fi
eval "echo "$input""
```

But the output is in a single line. I experimented with `${}` and `cat <<` tricks, but none of the experiments gave me the desired output.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: Syntax highlighting should show you the problem on the `eval` line.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - since `echo` and `HEREDOC` failed, I tried this, and it almost worked.

@choroba - I know that using quotes like this is wrong, but all other combination of single or/and double quotes give me error `line 15: $'\E[1m\E[31m': command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval "echo \"$( echo "${input}" )\""
```

but why not directly a sed (here using your variable name and content by substitution

```
cat > | sed "s/\$error/${error}/g;s/\$fatal/${fatal}/g;s#\$defaults#${defaults}#g'
```

Comment: Both of your answers work perfectly, thank you. I can see no significant difference in speed between `sed` substitution and variable `eval`uation (I am talking about `cat`enating huge files).

Comment: if you know the file name instead of send it as a stream via several cat, used the file name directly in sed (last argument) and not cat at all. It should be faster avoiding several cat + shell fork + temporary internal file